# Set control A to a specific value if control B is ever changed?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I've had trouble with this and issues similar to this in the past, where I need to track when a controlled variable is changed. Basically I have two `Sliders` (call them `A` and `B`) and whenever `B` is changed with its slider, `A` should be reset to some value, let's say it should be reset to 10 anytime `B` is changed.

In some way, shape, or form, I have never been able to come up with a reasonable solution to problems like these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do this. My current favorite is

```
Manipulate[{a, b},
 {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10, TrackingFunction -> (b = #; a = 10; &)}]
```