# Using TrackingFunction to set a Control variable for multiple Controls more efficiently

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

The variable `t` needs to reset to 0 if any of the other variables `tab1`, `tab2`, or `x` are changed. I did this by using `TrackingFunction` on each `Control`. What I would like to know is if there is a better, more efficient way of doing this without having to repeat `TrackingFunction` for each `Control`.

```
Manipulate[t,
 {{tab1, 1, ""}, {1, 2, 3}, TrackingFunction -> (tab1 = #; t = 0; &)},
 {{tab2, 1, ""}, {"A", "B"}, RadioButton, TrackingFunction -> (tab2 = #; t = 0; &)},
 {{x, 0}, 0, 10, 1, TrackingFunction -> (x = #; t = 0; &)},
 {{t, 0, "play"}, 0, 5, 1, Trigger}
 ]
```

Based on the answer to this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87666/set-control-a-to-a-specific-value-if-control-b-is-ever-changed/87671#87671).

Answer (score 3):

In your current code the resetting of `t` is driven by the `Control` object events.
The same `Manipulate` behavior can be achieved by using a [table-driven state model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) instead of such an [event driven model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming):

```
Manipulate[
 If[{tab1, tab2, x} === {tab1O, tab2O, xO}, t, {tab1O, tab2O, xO} = {tab1, tab2, x}; t = 0],
 {{tab1, 1, ""}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{tab2, 1, ""}, {"A", "B"}, RadioButton},
 {{x, 0}, 0, 10, 1},
 {{t, 0, "play"}, 0, 5, 1, Trigger},
 {tab1O, None}, {tab2O, None}, {xO, None}]
```

Or

```
Manipulate[
 If[{tab1, tab2, x} === last, t, last = {tab1, tab2, x}; t = 0],
 {{tab1, 1, ""}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{tab2, 1, ""}, {"A", "B"}, RadioButton},
 {{x, 0}, 0, 10, 1},
 {{t, 0, "play"}, 0, 5, 1, Trigger},
 {last, None}]
```

This is a different approach to the same problem. I leave it up to you, to judge if it is "a better, more efficient way". Instead of repeating `TrackingFunction` you have to introduce at least one additional variable.